# Can a star schema be implemented for descriptive-only data in Power BI?

Tags: data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, star-schema

Can you implement a star schema for data that is descriptive only and not quantitative?

I've taken a Udemy course on Power BI and learned that FACT tables consists of quantitative data and foreign keys. I have a catalogue of online courses (course title, comments about the course, course  content, modality etc.) that I want to use the star schema on that only has descriptive data. Does the star schema work for this?

Comment: Is there any "event" or "business process" that you need to track, i.e. how many students enrolled/started/complete the online course per term? That's a fact table. You don't _have_ to implement a star schema for analytics at all. For a data model that has no "process" or "transactions" in it, you're probably fine to directly use your existing data model as is. Don't complicate it by adding a step that transforms it into a half baked star schema if it's not necessary

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid without a star schema, OP runs the risk of auto-exists and may get incorrect output without even knowing it. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-dax-auto-exist/

Comment: @DavidBacci Thanks for linking that article. My love/hate relationship with DAX grows. My rather over simplified take on it is: Given a valid and unambiguous data model (i.e. a fully normalised one), you'll get the wrong (unexpected) answer if you build the DAX / slicers wrong. It just doesn't seem right to me that you'd need to fiddle the data model to get DAX to give you the right answer, to allow for some under the covers optimisation. Especially when the source data model doesn't even have data that can be used to create a fact table.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I completely agree with you. This is one of the biggest traps in PBI and I long for the day when it is "fixed".

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid mainly which regions are taking which courses and comments from the different regions about the courses. Thanks for the tip, I'll try to keep it simple!

Comment: But the regions will be taking different courses at different _times_ right? So region 1 will be taking course A 15 times in 2022, but region 1 will be taking course A 7 times in 2023. Is that something you need to report on? If so you need a fact table to model that.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid More on if the course is recommended in the region and people's feedback about it so the way I'm envisioning it is it's like a frequency table.